# Why is my second table range not transferring over to destination worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a script that combines two worksheets into a comprehensive worksheet: `legal_ws` + `cib_ws` ---> `comp_ws`

The `legal_ws` moves over just fine with this:

```
        lrow = legal_ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lcol = legal_ws.Cells(1, legal_ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

and

```
Set legal_rng = legal_ws.Range(legal_ws.Cells(2, 1), legal_ws.Cells(lrow, lcol))
```

and this

```
legal_rng.Copy Destination:=comp_ws.Range("A2")
```

but the `cib_ws` method of transferring it the same way doesn't work. the `cib_ws` transfer requires an autofilter and copy only visible cells minus the header, but it's not copying those cells.

```
        lrow2 = cib_ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lcol2 = cib_ws.Cells(1, cib_ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set cib_rng = cib_ws.Range(cib_ws.Cells(2, 1), cib_ws.Cells(lrow, lcol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        With cib_ws.Range("A1" & lcol2)
                    .AutoFilter
                    .AutoFilter Field:=61, Criteria1:="Regional Presidents"
        End With

            cib_rng.Copy Destination:=comp_ws.Range("A" & lrow3 + 1)
```

Why isn't the `cib_ws` transfer working but the `legal_ws` one is?

Here's the whole script:

```
    Sub TCR_Update()



    'File Paths
    Dim Legal As String, CIB As String, Comp_TCR As String

    Legal = "M:\Legal-TCR-Template.xlsx"
    CIB = "M:\CIB-TCR-Template.xlsx"
    Comp_TCR = "M:\Total_TCR.xlsx"

    Dim legal_wb As Workbook, cib_wb As Workbook, comp_wb As Workbook
    Set legal_wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Legal)
    Set cib_wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=CIB)
    Set comp_wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Comp_TCR)

    Dim legal_ws As Worksheet, cib_ws As Worksheet, comp_ws As Worksheet
    Set legal_ws = legal_wb.Sheets("ps")
    Set cib_ws = cib_wb.Sheets("ps")
    Set comp_ws = comp_wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim lrow As Long, lcol As Long, lrow2 As Long, lcol2 As Long, lrow3 As Long

    Dim legal_rng As Range



            lrow = legal_ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            lcol = legal_ws.Cells(1, legal_ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            lrow2 = cib_ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            lcol2 = cib_ws.Cells(1, cib_ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
           lrow3 = comp_ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                Set legal_rng = legal_ws.Range(legal_ws.Cells(2, 1), legal_ws.Cells(lrow, lcol))
                Set cib_rng = cib_ws.Range(cib_ws.Cells(2, 1), cib_ws.Cells(lrow, lcol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


        legal_rng.Copy Destination:=comp_ws.Range("A2")

            With cib_ws.Range("A1" & lcol2)
                        .AutoFilter
                        .AutoFilter Field:=61, Criteria1:="Regional Presidents"
            End With

                cib_rng.Copy Destination:=comp_ws.Range("A" & lrow + 1)

              legal_wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
              cib_wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

            Cells.Select
            Cells.Copy
            Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


              With comp_ws
              .Cells.WrapText = False
              .Rows.AutoFit
              .Columns.AutoFit
              End With
```

Comment: I'm wondering. The life of question is 1 minute - and it already got +1

Comment: @JohnyL, lol I have no clue

Comment: `With cib_ws.Range("A1" & lcol2)` should probably be: `With cib_ws.Range("A1", cib_ws.Cells(Lrow2,lcol2))`

Comment: @ScottCraner and that will still only select visible cells after the filter?

Comment: @bloomfieldhero9219 you've got the order backwards. First autofilter, and then `Set cib_rng` equal to the resulting visible cells.

Comment: all I know is `With cib_ws.Range("A1" & lcol2)` is only select one cell.  Say `lcol2` is 50.  The cell it is selecting is `A150` as the two get concatenated.

Comment: @ScottCraner That didn't select and copy any of the cells, that part is only autofiltering (which is working just fine), it's the copying that autofiltered section and transferring it to the `comp_ws` last row +1 offset that isn't working

Comment: See @BigBen comment and move the set cib_rng line after the filter.

Answer (score 0):

The main issues:

1. Use `lrow2` and `lcol2` instead of `lrow` and `lcol` (must just be a simple oversight).
2. As @Scott Craner pointed out in the comments, `With cib_ws.Range("A1" & lcol2)` refers to *one cell*, not the *entire range to be auto filtered*. That should probably be changed to `With cib_ws.Range("A1", cib_ws.Cells(Lrow2,lcol2))`
3. Switch the order around: **first** auto filter, and **then** `Set cib_rng` equal to the resulting visible cells. Note that you need to test if there are any visible cells before attempting to copy, otherwise `cib_rng` will be `Nothing`. So wrap your `cib_rng.Copy` statement within an `If Not cib_rng Is Nothing Then...End If`.

Comment: this still only copies over the legal_ws data, doesn't select and copy the cib_ws data

Comment: `Set cib_rng = cib_ws.Range(cib_ws.Cells(2, 1), cib_ws.Cells(lrow2, lcol2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` 

after the filter

Comment: the if not statement wrapped around 

`With cib_ws.Range(cib_ws.Cells(2, 1), cib_ws.Cells(lrow2, lcol2)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            .Copy Destination:=comp_ws.Range("A" & lrow3 + 1)`